# Mobile Device Lockdown (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, lockdown

So, I'm creating my first custom android app and expect to deploy it internally on company-owned devices. There's offline data storage that happens in a SQLite database. I want to ensure that the users *cannot* remove my application and/or destroy this database (which seems to happen when the app is uninstalled). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That is strange. Why is that neccessary?

Comment: I guess you could root the phone then change permissions, and then deny a normal user root...

Comment: One year ago I would have answered your question with "register your app as Device admin". However that API is now deprecated but will still work for devices that are published before 2019.

Comment: there is no way to be 100% sure that your app is not removable. User can always root the phone and removeanything he wants

Comment: I'm hoping that nobody is rooting the phones... definitely not worried that the users will. I just want to make it harder than a drag, drop and GONE scenario, if that makes sense.